# How do I open an editor window?

Tags: interface, node-editor

I am working to create a specific design following a video tutorial. I can't anyhow seem to open the editor with the white check mark, in the image below.

[image: image showing which window is marked]

Comment: Do you mean the panel on the bottom? Or the "T"/"N" panels? If it's not those then I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Please take a look at the blender manual: https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/introduction.html and https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/headers.html and: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/index.html Learning how to use the interface will save you a lot of time and problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a ***Tool Shelf panel*** click the little **'+'** symbol on the left of the window or press the <kbd>T</kbd> button. You may open the ***Properties panel*** in the same way, but instead of pressing <kbd>T</kbd>, you press the <kbd>N</kbd> button.
[image]